# Paperclip create images with the wrong access rights

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, permissions, imagemagick, paperclip

On my production server (ubuntu), i can add images using paperclip (stored in public), and i can delete them, however when accessing those images with a browser i have a forbidden error.

My ruby user is admin, if i create a file in the public folder the access rights are : `-rw-r--r--`

The folders and images created with paperclip use these rights: `drwxr-x---`

All of them belong to `admin admin`

How can i set my rails/ruby/paperclip/imagemagick to copy file using the same permission than the ones I get when creating files with admin user?